# Representing the gamma function as an infinite sum

Tags: limits, gamma-function

So I managed to come up with a limit that seems to be approaching the gamma function for all non integer positive numbers, here it is

$$ \lim{x\to \infty} \sum_{a=0}^x \frac  {\prod_{n=0}^x (p-n)}{(p-a)(a!)^2(-1)^{a+x}(x-a)!} = \frac {1}{\Gamma (p+1)} $$

However my only method of checking it is with desmos which can't calculate factorials for 170 and up and I don't have a proof for it , it just seems to work

Here is a desmos link to show it and compare it with other know formulas :https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ls7zx6ungh

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking for a proof of it?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find the equation online so I don't know if the statement is true or not